# real time chat system does not work properly javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

so far this code works if you click the button after writing the message. I am now trying to turn it into a real time system where as when you click the send button other people can see the message without refreshing browser. How do I do this? so far only if I don't have to refresh but others have to.

I tried to use the interval but it throws errors undefined data.

Thank you for you time.

here is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    /*
     * click after writing chat will echo the message
     */
    $('#insert-button').click(function () {
        chatonClick();
    });
});

function chatonClick() {
    /*
     * user enter text in text area
     */
    var _userId = $('#userId').val();
    var _userName = $('#userName').val();
    var _text = $('#chat-text').val();
    if (_text.length > 0 && _userId != null) {
        $('.insert-text-container').css('border', '1px solid #e1e1e1');
        $.post("/ajax/chat-insert.php", {
            task: "chat-insert",
            userId: _userId,
            text: _text
        }).error(function (data) {
            console.log("error:");
        }).success(function (data) {
            chatInsert(jQuery.parseJSON(data)).html(data);
            console.log("responseText:" + data);
        });
        console.log(_text + "userName: " + _userName + "userId: " + _userId);
    } else {
        $('.insert-text-container').css('border', '1px solid #ff0000');
        console.log("emty chat");
    }
    /*
     * the chat box will refresh after user click send
     */
    $('#chat-text').val("");
}

function chatInsert(data) {
    var c = '';
    c += '<li class="chat-holder" id= "_' + data.chat.chat_id + '">';
    c += '<div class="user-img">';
    c += '<img src="' + data.user.user_image + '" class="user-img-pic"/>';
    c += '</div>';
    c += '<div class="chat-body">';
    c += '<div class="username-field"><strong>' + data.user.userName + '</strong></div>';
    c += '<div class="chat-text">' + data.chat.text + '</div>';
    c += '</div>';
    c += '<div class="chats-button-holder">';
    c += '<ul>';
    c += '<li id="' + data.chat.chat_id + '" class="delete-button">x</li>';
    c += '</ul>';
    c += '</div>';
    c += '</li>';
    $('.chats-holder-ul').prepend(c);
    addDeleteHandlers();
}
setInterval(function () {
    chatInsert(data);
}, 2500)
```

Comment: You want to get data when it is available without updating the browser. This has been addressed many times, see for example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13915404/can-i-keep-pushing-data-from-the-server-to-the-same-connection), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21493181/send-an-http-request-and-receive-push-data/21535950#21535950) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629642/how-can-i-refresh-a-page-when-a-database-is-updated).

Comment: `chatInsert(jQuery.parseJSON(data)).html(data);` doesn't make sense. `undefined` doesn't have an `html` method.

Comment: I was just trying to find a solution.

Comment: You can do it by using ajax and database. Create a table in database where you will store messages from users. So when someone wants to send message, he will send it into the database by ajax. Last thing you need is ajax call which executes every 5 seconds, and checking if there are new messages in database.